# xorg and modelines for sony Bravia KDL-40CX523

Tags: 11.10, xorg, sony, modelines

Does anyone know where I can find the correct modelines so I can configure my Sony TV to be recognised and have full (or close to) HD resolution?

Intel 965 GM graphics, i know it's not the best but Window$ will configure it, surely Ubuntu can to?

Answer (score 1):

My sony tv (not the same model as yours) was also not detected

I ran

```
get-edid | parse-edid
```

from the command line to get the required settings and then run these commands on startup:

```
xrandr --newmode 1360x768 85.5 1360 1424 1536 1792 768 771 777 795 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --newmode 1920x1080 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1360x768
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080
```